# Distributed Tensorflow VS Tensorflow on Spark

Tags: tensorflow, clustering, apache-spark

I am new to Deep Learning and Tensorflow. I learned TensorFlow can be code to run in stand-alone mode and in distributed mode. I also came across Tensorflow on Spark framework that will allow the Tensorflow to run with Spark. Which one is good in runtime performance? I didn't find any resource on this point could someone share their experience?

Thanks